# How to call a c# web service from unmanaged c application

Tags: c, wcf, c++-cli, unmanaged, dllexport

I have the following architecture:
-1 c# wcf web service
-1 c# console application
-1 c++ class library
-Microsoft sample key storage provider in c.
What I want to do is to call the web service, in that sample key storage provider. I used a class with a method in that c# console application to consume that web service and that's working great. I used that c++ class library as a wrapper over that c# console application.
Ok, now I created a .h file and .c file in the provider project where I try to load the dll created by the library class and after all, to use it in provider's OpenKey function. This files look like:
.h

```
#pragma once      
//Declare ITEM struct again (the same definition from dll sources)    
typedef struct {    
unsigned char* data;
unsigned int len;
} ITEM;


//Declare function pointers
typedef ITEM(*_fptr_callWS)   (char*, ITEM, char*); //pointer to a function 
with the following signature:  ITEM function_name (char* ,ITEM ,char* )
typedef void(*_fptr_freeITEM) (ITEM); //pointer to a function with the 
following signature: void function_name (ITEM )

                                      /*The ITEM returned is freed using 
freeItem(ITEM) function*/
ITEM callWS(char* myAlias, ITEM hash, char* myPassword);

/*This function deletes an item which was returned from callWS(...) 
function*/
void freeITEM(ITEM item);
```

.c

```
#include"dllWrapper.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

ITEM callWS(char* myAlias, ITEM hash, char* myPassword)
{
ITEM signature;
signature.data = NULL;
signature.len = 0;

//Load DLL
HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibraryA("serviceConsumerWrapper.dll");
if (!dllHandle)
{
    printf("Error loading serviceConsumerWrapper.dll\n");
    return signature;
}

//Get callWS function pointer from loaded DLL
_fptr_callWS fptrCallWS = (_fptr_callWS)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "callWS");
if (!fptrCallWS)
{
    printf("Error loading callWS function pointer\n");
    return signature;
}

//call function callWS using function pointer
return fptrCallWS(myAlias, hash, myPassword);

}


void freeITEM(ITEM item)
{
//Load DLL
HINSTANCE dllHandle = LoadLibraryA("serviceConsumerWrapper.dll");
if (!dllHandle)
{
    printf("Error loading serviceConsumerWrapper.dll\n");
    return;
 }

//Get callWS function pointer from loaded DLL
_fptr_freeITEM fptrFreeItem = (_fptr_freeITEM)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 
"freeITEM");
if (!fptrFreeItem)
{
    printf("Error loading freeITEM function pointer\n");
    return;
}

//call function freeITEM using function pointer
fptrFreeItem(item);
```

}

Ok, now I try to use that functions in my provider. I include the "wrapper.h" and I try to use the functions. I recognises them, but I still get a linker error.

```
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  provider    
E:\Licenta_2016_Urian\New_site\Debug\SampleKSP.dll  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _callWS referenced in function 
_SampleKSPOpenKey@20    provider    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\8.0\Cryptographic Provider Development 
Kit\Samples\KeyStorageProviderSample\CPP\Provider\SampleKSP.obj 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _freeITEM referenced in function 
_SampleKSPOpenKey@20    provider    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\8.0\Cryptographic Provider Development 
Kit\Samples\KeyStorageProviderSample\CPP\Provider\SampleKSP.obj 1
```

By the way, I used dumpbin on the dll created by that class library and it seems to export the functions properly.

Comment: The idea is that I don't want to use Windows Services if it is possible.